# Short-run dynamics in VECM

Tags: cointegration, granger-causality, vector-error-correction-model

I am currently trying to grasp Jesus Gonzalo's and Clive Granger's measure, proposed in ["Estimation of Common Long-Memory Components in Cointegrated Systems"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1392518) (1995), with which one can analyze relationships between variables.

Although I do not yet fully understand the theory behind it, I have realized that lots of researchers who are working with cointegrated economic data are using a relatively straightforward version of the GG-measure (applied on the error correction term coefficients) when they want to determine which variable reacts faster to news, e.g. newly published GDP forecasts etc.

**My questions:**

1. Is the GG-measure a valid replacement for Granger causality tests with which one would normally check "what variable moves first"?

What I know: Granger causality tests are usually used for this task and I cannot think of why many researchers are not using them for it.

2. A simplified form of the GG-measure is often used, where the coefficients on the error correction term are used to determine short-run dynamics and I wonder why Granger causality tests are not used instead since their characteristics can be modified such that they are useable even for cointegrated data - why do people care about the ECT?

Comment: AFAIK, Granger causality is not about which variable moves first. How would you explain that?

Comment: You are right. Technically, it is not about which variable moves first. I was referring to contexts in which one wants to find out whether X or Y "moves first", given a certain change in the system. GC tests are often applied in these situations.

Comment: So how do they work there? Can they actually help answer the question of which one moves first? Would you have any reference that shows this clearly?

Comment: For example, Smith (2000, p. 189) mentions: "A Granger analysis attempts to determine whether the movements in one variable temporally precede or temporally follow the movements in another variable, the casual direction outlined in this chapter would be supported. If media coverage changes first and then public mood shifts in the same direction, […]. By contrast, if public mood moves first and the media coverage follows, the alternative […]"

Smith, Mark A., 2000, _American Business and Political Power: Public Opinion, Elections, and Democracy_ (University of Chicago Press, Chicago)

Comment: It becomes evident that the author would like to ascertain whether media coverage or public mood "moves first".

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to your question.

Comment: That's okay, maybe someone else will happen to know the answer :)